# Null Uri while running the swagger url

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to do a set up of swagger ui,but am not able to do the same with the swagger-ui-master code copied from the URL https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.

Downloaded the above , copied the contents under dist anf placed them under my web application context under src/main/webapp and do a maven build.I try to deploy the same in the tomcat box and I edit the index.html file to point to the path  with http://localhost:8080//test.json which gives me comprehensive list of the api's in JSON format.

I am seeing error response in JSON format as

```
{
"status": "notFound",
"errorMessage": "null for uri: http://localhost:8080/<webapp_context>/index.html",
"errorCode": null,
"additional": null
}
```

Any pointers.Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is unclear what you're doing when you get that error. Do you open a specific URL? Do you see the error in your browser? Logs?

Comment: @Ron thanks for the reply.There was no error since the deployment was not fine.Since there was no documentation I was missing few steps while making the swagger run.By the JSON i meant the integration of  Swagger jars to get rest API documentation in JSON format which was working well , but the feed of that JSON to the swagger ui was not working.I could figure out the second part by properly deploiying the swagger-ui dist folder in tomcat and editing the index.html pointing to the JSON url.Thanks again.